# Freeze cloth simulation at a given frame

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I had created a room in blender 2.8 .Here it is:
[image]
 I used Cloth simulation for a bed sheet. It was 50 frames long and I liked the 22nd frame.This is it  (Leave the cylinder):
[image]
 Now I want to make a camera moving animation but I cant 'cause I created a cloth simulation which plays along it. I want help to make the sheet a 39th frame to be an own object, how can I ?

Comment: Why it is a problem for camera animation? Use [Dope sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db6ZIRLFeHk).

Comment: if you mean you don't want the cloth animation to play anymore you can apply it: go to the sheet modifier panel and click Apply at the frame you want, now it keeps its appearance